# sending notification from device to an other using FCM with android

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

I want to send notification from a device to an other using the same mobile application. Actually my application contains 2 types of clients so the first type send a notification and the other receive it.
I tried pushing notification with the firebase consol, but this is not what I really need. I want it between devices.
Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good tutorial here: [Push Notifications through PHP](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

This is assuming you have an understanding of PHP.

The downside to using this method is that you need to have a PHP server that will be in charge of running your PHP scripts.

You may read more about the method used in the tutorial from: [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)